# How to check the type of object in ArrayList

Tags: c#, object, types, arraylist

Is there a way to get the type of object in the arraylist?

I need to make an IF statment as the following (in C#):

```
if(object is int)
 //code
else
 //code
```

thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use the normal GetType() and typeof()

```
if( obj.GetType() == typeof(int) )
{
    // int
}
```

Answer (score 16):

What you are doing is fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add("one");
    foreach (object obj in list) {
        if (obj is int) {
            Console.WriteLine((int)obj);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("not an int");
        }
    }
}
```

If you were checking for a reference type instead of a value type, you could use the `as` operator, so that you would not need to check the type first and then cast:

```
    foreach (object obj in list) {
        string str = obj as string;
        if (str != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("not a string");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `GetType()` to know the type of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much how you do it:

```
if (theArrayList[index] is int) {
   // unbox the integer
   int x = (int)theArrayList[index];
} else {
   // something else
}
```

You can get a Type object for the object, but then you should make sure that it's not a null reference first:

```
if (theArrayList[index] == null) {
  // null reference
} else {
  switch (theArrayList[index].GetType().Name) {
    case "Int32":
      int x = (int)theArrayList[index];
      break;
    case "Byte":
      byte y = (byte)theArrayList[index];
      break;
  }
}
```

Note that unless you are stuck with framework 1.x, you shouldn't use the `ArrayList` class at all. Use the `List<T>` class instead, where you should use a more specific class than `Object` if possible.

Comment: It would be better to extract value from the list using indexer only once and then cast it to the necessary type.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, that is correct. I wrote the example to demonstrate the type recognition and casting, it's not optimal in other aspects.